# How to change input value and make it valid after button clicked in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an input field and add button in a component.

Button is disabled at first, when user enters valid format url, button becomes active, then button add this domain to db, refresh table(which is in another component). I want to achieve that, after button is clicked it makes input field empty (refresh like page is just opened)

My component template is

```
<form #addDomainForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addClicked()">
  <mat-card class="topia-box-shadow">

    <mat-card-content fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="left" fxLayoutGap="16px">

      <div>
        <p>Enter domain name or copy and paste the full link to add its domain
          to white list</p>

        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Enter link here</mat-label>
          <input type="url" matInput [(ngModel)]="domainName" #url="ngModel"
                 [class.is-invalid]="url.invalid && url.touched"
                 name="url" [pattern]="urlValidationRegexPattern" required>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-error *ngIf="url.invalid && (url.dirty || url.touched)">
          Please enter the link in correct format
        </mat-error>
      </div>

    </mat-card-content>

    <button type="button" id="search" class="topia-btn topia-primary-btn action-buttons"
            [disabled]="!addDomainForm.valid" (click)="addClicked()">Add
      Domain
    </button>
  </mat-card>
</form>
```

My ts file for that component:

```
export class DomainWhiteListingAddComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output()
  domainAdded = new EventEmitter<true>();
  domainName: string;
  public urlValidationRegexPattern = /^((((https?)(:\/\/))?((www)\.)?)?|mailto:(\w+\.?\w+)\@)([a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+)+((\/([\w#]+|[\w#]+(([.\w#])*(-\w+|=\w+|\?\w+=\w+(&\w+=(\w)+)*)?)+)+))*$/;

  constructor(private globalSettingService: GlobalSettingsService, private dialog: MatDialog) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addClicked() {
    const newDomainModel = {
      id: null, domain: this.domainName, disabled: false
    } as Domain;
    this.globalSettingService.addDomainToList(newDomainModel)
      .subscribe((data: Domain) => {
        this.domainAdded.emit(true);
      }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        this.showErrorDialog(error.error);
      });
  }
}
```

This code is working but after clicking button and adding the element, input box value still stays there.
if i add a single line code to .ts file **addClicked()** method

```
this.domainName = null;
```

this time, input field becomes empty as I wanted but it appears as invalid so it shows error. I just want it make as default like the page is opened at beginning. Like
[image: Thats how i want after button is clicked and element is added]

But it shows as:
[image: How it shows]
How can I do that ? (if it is needed i can add parent component codes and other component code also)

Or if it is needed; how can i reset just that component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
@ViewChild(addDomainForm) formDirective: FormGroupDirective;

addClicked() {
 this.formDirective.resetForm();
}
```

It'll reset your form as you are checking if the form is `dirty`

Comment: where to add this code ? into parent component ts ?

Comment: @abidinberkay :yeah, in `DomainWhiteListingAddComponent ` where you have `addClicked`.

Comment: addDomainForm is not reachable. The code cannot resolve it.

Comment: in your answer instead of formDirective i have wrote addDomainForm and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You are making the `ngModel` domainName as `null` so it throws error.
Change it like `this.domainName = ''`

Comment: no it doesnt work. because ' ' empty character is also invalid for regex.

Answer (score 0):

Along with setting the `ngModel`  to it's original value, empty or null. You should also set your form `asPristine`.

If you are using Template-Driven forms and you have something like this in your component:  `@ViewChild('myForm') myform: any;`

You can use the `markAsPristine()`  function on the form property of your form. So it would be `this.myform.form.markAsPristine()`.

Comment: I did not understand what you have said.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML you use `url.invalid && url.touched`to add the invalid red class, perhaps try this instead:

```
[class.is-invalid]="url.invalid && url.dirty"
```

This way it's not flagged as invalid until the value as actually changed.

Comment: same problem. if i add this.domainName = null; to ts file, still deletes the value but shows error. this.domainName = '' is also same problem